# In a Java project with many similar microservices that return similar JSON payloads, why should constants be used for keys rather than String literals

Tags: java, json, constants, key

Imagine you have one class file for one handler. And each handler is going to return a JSON payload. The JSON payloads are going to be very similar for Handler1, Handler2, etc.

They might be: username, somethingId, anotherId, thisId, thatId.

In a Handler class, there will be the area that you are constructing the JSON payload.

```
JsonObject toReturn = new JsonObject();
toReturn.put(USERNAME, ...)
.put(SOMETHING_ID, ...)
.put(ANOTHER_ID, ...)
.put(THIS_ID, ...)
.put(THAT_ID, ...);
```

Why is it better to use constants there rather than String literals? Why not just do:

```
JsonObject toReturn = new JsonObject();

toReturn.put("username", ...)
.put("somethingId", ...)
.put("anotherId", ...)
.put("thisId", ...)
.put("thatId", ...);
```

The only good reason I can see for using a constant is that, should we wish to change USERNAME from "username" to "userName", we would only need to do so in one spot. Whereas the Find-And-Replace-In-Project operation modifies many files.

I argue that using the String literal is clearer. This is because, later, when you are debugging your results from Postman, you will be reading the exact key that you're expecting. If you don't remember what the constant was for that key, you have to search for the key in the project. This takes you to the constants file, which allows you to check for the usages of that constant. This is just an extra middle man. Why not just search for the String literal and get taken to the class in the first place?

As an illustration, what do you think of the proposal of a RetrieveConstant class? And in this class, you provide a constant, like USERNAME, and it returns to you the value of Constants.USERNAME?

It should be clear that this middleman class is a useless middleman. That's how I feel about the use of a constants class (with many constants for short string literals) between the programmer and the class that uses the String ultimately.

I think a constants class can be good sometimes, when the String literal is very long. But in this very real world example of having multiple microservices that return similar JSON payloads, what possible rationale can be given for making constants out of the String literals for the keys of the JSON payloads?

Is this just a matter of style? I feel there is something about objective engineering here, which my RetrieveConstants middleman should highlight.

Constants should not be longer or harder to remember than the literals they are to assist.

Comment: If you use the same value in multiple places, you can reuse the constant and thus ensure consistency across those multiple places. However, your question is basically soliciting opinions and thus off-topic. Personally, I would never create JSON this way, but instead use a POJO and serialize it with Jackson (or Gson if I really have to).

Comment: `USERNAME = "username"` is functionally useless. If you ever need to change it, so you have something like `USERNAME = "employee_id"`, you are left with a constant with a confusing name.  If you don't see that, consider `THREE = 3`.  How would you like to work on code where THREE had the value 4?  This isn't to say that named constants are bad, just that names need to be well-considered. What is the name **for**?

Comment: On the other side of the coin, if you have multiple data structures, many might have a "username" field.  Now consider the case where just one of them needs a field-name change. A blanket replace of the literal "username" will cause chaos.

Comment: @accessviolation If it needed to be changed in only one spot, then you wouldn't do a Find-And-Replace-In-Project.,

If USERNAME = "username" and we want to change it to "userName" in 5 out of 20 spots, whether we have USERNAME typed or "username" typed, we're still going to have to go manually replace whatever's there with "userName". 

Whether we used the constant or the String literal it is the same amount of refactoring effort.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Would you agree that my example of a useless middleman RetrieveConstant.getConstant() would be horrendous design, and that this is not merely a matter of opinion, but it is an objective fact of engineering? 

Why isn't "constants standing in for small String literals" an equally horrendous design according to objective standards? I think if one is not a matter of opinion, the other one shouldn't be considered a matter of opinion either. I'm fine with anyone considering both a matter of opinion, but I don't consider my example of RetrieveConstant to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @user1886458 - I think you missed my point. In your question, you suggested IDE "find and replace" as an alternative to using a USERNAME definition.  With USERNAME, when it's only the field name in one structure (not every structure with a "username") that has changed, there is only one string to replace (assuming some sanity that defines USERNAME in the scope of each applicable structure - a global USERNAME applied to multiple structures introduces horrible coupling between the structures).  But find-and-replace on the literal is not sensitive to which actual structure the literal is used in.

Comment: Qualifications like "horrendous design" prove that this is a matter of opinion. And using strawmans as if you'd use a single constant for everything with the same name, instead of correctly scoped constants for things that represent the exact same thing (and thus would evolve/change all at the same time), or that you couldn't rename constants don't make that different. If you consider things like writing the JSON and reading the JSON, or tests, defining constants can make sense even if you define a constant only for one field, because you'd use it in at least two places.

Comment: But I repeat, that personally, I wouldn't even define JSONs in that way, I'd create POJOs and use those for serialization and deserialization.